# XNA How To Make Camera Orbit Around And Always Look At A Vector3.Zero?

Tags: xna

Halo everyone,

How to make a camera **orbiting a Vector3.Zero** within a certain distance (like the earth orbiting sun) **AND** make the camera always look at that Vector3.Zero?

Please kindly answer, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The camera is usually passed to effects as a `View` matrix.

You can create a "look at" matrix with `Matrix.CreateLookAt` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195650.aspx)).

That takes three arguments: the target and up vectors should be pretty standard (presumably `Vector3.Zero` and `Vector3.Up` in your case).

Now you just need the position of the camera itself. And you want it to rotate. It will be something like this:

```
Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(distance, 0, 0), Matrix.CreateRotationY(angle));
```

For more information, take a look at the [methods that the `Matrix` class provides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197914.aspx) for creating transformation matrices.